# Update Embedded Mongo Document Field Without Affecting Other Fields

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

I have the following code that performs basic updates on a Mongo document. The problem is that after I run the `/stop/:id` route, the `startDate` field gets deleted from the embedded document. How can I make sure it stays there after the `endDate` and `started` fields are updated?

```
router.get('/start/:id', function(req,res){
    var collection = db.get('Activity');
    collection.update({
        _id: req.params.id
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "runtime": {
                    started: true,
                    startDate: new Date(),
                    endDate: null
            }
        }
    }, function(err, activity){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(activity);
    });
});

router.get('/stop/:id', function(req,res){
    var collection = db.get('Activity');
    collection.update({
        _id: req.params.id
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "runtime.started": false,
            "runtime.endDate": new Date()       
        }
    }, function(err, activity){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(activity);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a working code for this:

```
router.get('/stop/:id', function(req,res){
    var collection = db.get('Activity');

    collection.update({
        _id: req.params.id
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "runtime.started": false,
            "runtime.endDate": new Date()
        }   
    }, 
    function(err, activity){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(activity);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Trh this using `$addToSet`

```
router.get('/stop/:id', function(req,res){
    var collection = db.get('Activity');
    collection.update({
        _id: req.params.id
    },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            "runtime.started": false,
            "runtime.endDate": new Date()       
        }
    }, function(err, activity){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(activity);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not going to work. $addToSet seems to be for adding elements to an array. In my case, I am trying to add / change elements on an embedded document.